# Do I need to use CryptoPP DLL with Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, dll, compilation, crypto++

So on [official Crypto++ Visual Studio Wiki page](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Visual_Studio) and [in this tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16388/Compiling-and-Integrating-Crypto-into-the-Microsof) it is mentioned, you must use CryptoPP as DLL when working with Qt.

But is this really true? Can't I just compile cryptlib as /MD and /MDd into `cryptlib.lib`, instead of `cryptopp.dll` and use that with my project? Why would I need to include external DLL?

I am struggling with compiling CryptoPP as DLL, so I would like to know if I am not just wasting my time and there is a way to use cryptlib.lib directly (compiled with correct Runtime /MD or /MDd)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do I need to use CryptoPP DLL with Qt?

No. But libraries like QT and MFC use dynamic C++ rumtimes, so you will need to switch to dynamic runtimes for Crypto++.

---

> But is this really true? Can't I just compile cryptlib as /MD and /MDd into cryptlib.lib, instead of cryptopp.dll and use that with my project? Why would I need to include external DLL?

Yes. Just change to the dynamic C++ runtime library, and then link to the static library.

---

> I am struggling with compiling CryptoPP as DLL

Yeah, its a pain. Folks should avoid it unless they have to use it.

---

> Why would anyone use dll other than the fips signed (which is already compiled)

Those doing business in US Federal and US DoD *must* use the FIPS version. They have no choice. The OMB does not allow agencies to use anything other than validated cryptography.

The DLL is special purpose. *If* you want the FIPS DLL, then you can only use it on Windows 2000 SP1, Windows XP SP3 and Windows Server 2003 SP1.

The DLL *only* has approved algorithms. Its missing a bunch of stuff, like utilities (i.e., `HexEncoder`) and non-approved algorithms (i.e., `MD5`, `Whirlpool`, `Camellia`, etc).

If you want to supplement the DLL, then you have to add the missing algorithms from the static LIB. As you can imagine, that's going to be a pain point.

The signature for integrity assurances is provided by SHA-1/HMAC using the static key `{0x47, 0x1E, 0x33, 0x96, 0x65, 0xB1, 0x6A, 0xED, 0x0B, 0xF8, 0x6B, 0xFD, 0x01, 0x65, 0x05, 0xCC}`. Anyone can tamper with it, and create valid signatures over it.

We created a page on the topic. You can find it on the Crypto++ wiki at [FIPS DLL](https://cryptopp.com/wiki/FIPS_DLL). It provides things like implementation details, and discusses things like Operational Environments.

Comment: Why would anyone use dll other than the fips signed (which is already compiled)

Comment: @TomášNavara - there are significant limitations when using the [FIPS DLL](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/FIPS_DLL). See the linked page for details. Also, its not signed, so integrity is tenuous and depends upon installing it into a read-only directory, which does not really exist in non-enterprise environments (all users are Admins). There is an HMAC under a fixed key, but anyone can calculate it and make it appear valid.